# Android loading large data in list view

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently i have 5MB sqlite database in my app i need to show almost all record in activity using into listView. In iPhone core data have facility to load 20 records at time and when need they load more data automatically so the performance of the app is more faster then Android app,can any one suggest me the better way to increase performance. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/60239-coredata-nsfetchedresultscontroller-performances.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same behavior with a CursorAdapter. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html and http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: it is not 100% but better then load data into Array and then pass it to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use CommonsWare's [Endless Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)

Comment: Link is 404 now.